# Why xrandr numerical output is VGA-1 instead of VGA1?

Tags: xrandr

Why xrandr numerical output is `VGA-1` instead of `VGA1`? The same behaviour hapens with `LVDS-1` instead of `LVDS1`.

I'm using Debian 9 stable and i3wm. Xrandr version 1.5.0. Laptop Thinkpad Lenovo.

However, in a second laptop (Acer Aspire One) the output is `LVDS1`. I'm using the same dotfiles for both laptops and I'm writing a script which should work in both. The script would help me to manage an external monitor (VGA). How can I solve this numerical difference?

Comment: I'd just remove the dash with `tr`.

Comment: I finally used a solution with bash and regex into a loop, like this one: http://infra.in.zekjur.net/archives/i3-discuss/2015-August/002148.html, so it will match also with different numbers after the dash. I'm not sure what would be the best, though. I like your idea using `tr` as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the name is dependent on the device driver as well as the kernel.  For example, I have a two graphic display ports resident on one graphics card on one of my computers, one is called DVI-D-1 and the other is called DVI-I-1.

Comment: Yes, probably it's something related with the hardware, therefore drivers as well. My two laptops are very different: Acer is 32 bits, very old one, 512 MB of RAM, while Thinkpad Lenovo is 64 bits, 4 GB, CPU i5... Acer has Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1, while Thinkpad has Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2.